# Laravel Livewire, form submit: do something first then submit the form

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire form which I intent to submit to an external url. However, before submitting, I want to programmatically add some hidden inputs which the user should not be able to edit then finally submit the form:

```
 <form action="some-external-url" wire:submit.prevent="processForm" method="post">
                <x-inputs.text-input wire:model="amount" name="amount" />
                <x-inputs.button title="Submit" />
            </form>
```

Something similar to this jQuery code:

```
$('form').submit( function(ev){
         ev.preventDefault();
         //fetch and add some additional fields to the form
         // finally submit the form
         $(this).unbind('submit').submit()

  });
```

How best can I achieve this using livewire. Please note that I dont intent to use guzzle to submit this form.

Comment: Why not sending a post request to the external url from your `processForm` method?

Comment: Please show me how!!

Comment: You can use `Http::asForm()->post('external-url.com', ['amount' => $this->amount]);` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#request-data

Answer (score 2):

If you want in your component you can set the properties, you need and then in your mount method, you initialise the value for those properties.
see [forms in livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation#real-time-validation)

```
class ComponentName extends Component
{
   public $hidden_val;
   


  public function mount() 
  {
     $this->hidden_val = "my_hidden_val";
  }
}
```

Then pass it with livewire

```
<input type="hidden" wire:model="hidden_val">
```

But I also think as @ClémentBaconnier and would suggest to pass to external link the data of form using Http Client provided by laravel in your controller or event within your livewire component.

```
Http::asForm()->post('some-external-url', ['form_data' => /*your form data*/]);
```

Follow it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#request-data)